# Fundamental trade offs in expressiveness?

Tags: language-design

Language designers and implementers face a number of trade offs.
The most obvious being over complexity of design & implementation versus how easy it is to understand or use a language.
The typical constraint is the "complexity budget" but if we ignore this and imagine we can create a kitchen sink language which supports as many features as we care to add what pairs of features if any are fundamentally at odds?

If you consider a pair of algorithms where one trades execution time for space. There can be a fundamental trade off there.
Are there similarly fundamental trades when designing a language.

Consider for example a pure object oriented langage vs a pure functional programming language this is a deliberate choice and not in itself a fundamental trade off. You can create a multi-paradigm language that supports both approaches as first class.
Some technical obstacles only become apparent when you begin implementation.
In some cases these might a complete re-design. It is important to try and think about them up front.
It is also worth considering if the trade offs are fundamental such that a pair of features in impossible to reconcile.
Are there any such pairs of features?

And for those that are reconcilable was there a unifying concept that helped.

What trade offs are you likely to run up against

For example I think we can reconcile functions vs objects.
Can we reconcile a condition system (like in LISP) with exceptions or with return codes?

Answer (score 1):

I consider Common Lisp to be such a kitchen sink: I picture a star plot of features where it scores approximately the same for different features; you can compile it, perform type inference and declare static types, define objects, macros, redefine classes at runtime etc. while not being exactly perfect in a given direction.

Compared to OCaml for example, which leans heavier towards Functional Programming, or Python which is even more dynamic than Lisp, or other languages which focus more on one or another philosophy of programming.

So it's not really impossible but there are different constraints that prevents things to be used at same time: you want both a GC and fine manual memory allocation, mutable objects with identity but also purely functional, immutable data, and fast arithmetic but also big integers, etc. you can define everything as different packages and it's up to the program to  make tradeoffs.